# How could id() function in python return memory address of an integer value without assignment it?

Tags: python

like this code: `id(1)` ,The output will be the memory address: 94591972181024 ,and if i assignment a variable `x = 1` and write `id(x) == id(1)`
it return `True` ...which means that the value of **x** which is **1**, stored in the same memory address as number **1**
...does it mean that every numerical value we store, they have a known place in memory before?

Comment: This should help explain it: ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers).

Comment: "does it mean that every numerical value we store, they have a known place in memory before?" No. this simply means that the object being referred to by `x` is *the same object* that is created by the literal expression `1`.

Comment: It is very important to understand, `id` *happens* to return the address of the PyObject header, but that is an implementation detail. It is simply supposed to return an integer that is *unique for the lifetime of the object*.

Comment: Also, it is important to understand that in Python, a variable **is not some space reserved in memory**. Rather, it is a name in some namespace (global, local, etc) that can refer to any object

Comment: *does it mean that every numerical value we store, they have a known place in memory before?* - How could you store *any* data without knowing where in memory you were storing it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)